# Is there an equivalent of pairwise_survdiff( ) that I can use on data with competing risks?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, statistical-test, survminer

I plotted cumulative incidence curves using this model fit:

```
cuminc(Surv(time, outcome) ~ time_per, data)
```

When I try plugging my data into pairwise_survdiff()

```
pairwise_survdiff(Surv(time, outcome) ~ time_per, data)
```

I get this warning message:

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In Surv(exposure_time, outcome) : Invalid status value, converted
> to NA
>
> 2: In Surv(exposure_time, outcome) : Invalid status value, converted
> to NA
>
> 3: In Surv(exposure_time, outcome) : Invalid status value, converted
> to NA

It's because my outcome variable has 3 levels (0=censored, 1=event of interest, 2=competing event). Is there a different method that I can use?